# Environment specific docker image from one Dockerfile

Tags: docker, asp.net-core

I have environment wise appsettings.json and one Dokcerfile in solution.

[image: solution-structure]

Should I now build environment wise separate images? If so, Is it possible to use this single Dockerfile to create environment wise docker images? Actually I want to know what is the best approach. I am using asp.net core.

Answer (score 1):

If possible, the best solution would be to have a single docker image that is built from a single Dockerfile, and then configuration happens entirely from the environment variables that are injected into the container at runtime. It is common to store these environment variables in a `.env` file (you could have a `dev.env`, `stage.env`, `prod.env` file, etc.) and then you could pick which one to use when you start the container with the `docker container run` flag `--env-file`.

Comment: This may not work when during the build process, unit test cases are executed. For example, for any maven project, when `mvn clean test package` command is fired to build the artifacts, we need environment at that time. So above solution will not work in every case.